# Popup window icon in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension that will open the currently-open tab in a popup window. This is my code:

```
function openAsPopup()
{
    chrome.tabs.query(
        {active: true, currentWindow: true},
        function(tabs)
        {
            currentTab = tabs[0]

            chrome.windows.create({
                "tabId": currentTab.id,
                "type":  "popup"
            })
        }
    )
}
```

The window generated by this code has a particular icon, which is not the script icon (far right):

[image]

How can I change this icon?

**Edit:** OK, so this icon is inherited from the manifest:

```
{
    ...
    "icons": {...},
    ...
}
```

Better question: how can I modify this icon *at runtime*? I would really like it to reflect the favicon of whatever tab is open, if possible.

Comment: Try setting a favicon inside the page html.

Comment: This will change the icon in the title bar, but not the taskbar.

Comment: Then it seems to be a limitation of Chrome, see if it's reported in https://crbug.com.

Comment: It's definitely possible, since another extension (Open-as-Popup) achieves it already. I can't find an open source implementation though.

Comment: Every extension's source can be trivially inspected both in devtools and on the disk in the browser directory. As you can see in the code of Open-as-Popup it uses absolutely the same API to create the popup so the difference is probably in its manifest.json, for example "icons" section.

Comment: The difference may be caused by the current tab, maybe Chrome simply shows its icon.

Answer (score -1):

### Add to menifest.json file

```
"icons": {"32": "images/icon32.png",
  "48": "images/icon48.png",
  "64": "images/icon64.png",
  "128": "images/icon128.png",
  "256": "images/icon256.png},
```